# Oracle PL SQL/Trigger before insert or delete or update on StmTbl

Tags: oracle, triggers

How can i avoid null value of :old or new?
Im trying  to insert to one table 3 step before update,delete,insert with having more columns

Comment: Please provide some sample code and data, your current result and expected result. It's not clear what you are doing  currently and what you want to achieve

Answer (score 0):

> How can i avoid null value of :old or new?

Both `old` and `new` pseudorecords reflect values in the table (old ones are "previous", new ones are ... well, "new", which will replace old ones).

**Suppose** there's a `job` column in the table and its value is `NULL`. If you run

```
update emp set job = 'CLERK' where empno = 7369;
```

then `:old.job = NULL`, `:new.job = 'CLERK'`.

Or, the **opposite**: suppose there was 'ANALYST' in that column and you run

```
update emp set job = null where empno = 7369;
```

so `:old.job = 'ANALYST'`, `:new.job = NULL`.

---

You asked how to avoid `null`; why would you want to "avoid" them? They have values they should have. There's nothing wrong in `NULL` as it means that there's an absence of a value.

In the 1st example above (where `:old.job = null`), what would you want to use instead of it? There was no value there ...

If you *must* (although, I don't know why), you could use `NVL` or `COALESCE` functions or `CASE` expression; for example:

```
insert into log_table (job) values (nvl(:old.job, 'no previous job'));

insert into log_table (job) values (coalesce(:old.job, 'no previous job'));

insert into log_table (job), values (case when :old.job is null then 'no previous job'
                                          else :old.job
                                     end);
```